# Firebase rules - allow users access only their own data

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am making a firebase notes app for android as a project (I'm a beginner and never done anything like this). My problem at the moment is that every note made, no matter what user made it, is available for every user to see. I want to make it that every user can only read/write their own notes but all the rules I found and tried so far made it that no notes are sent to the database at all or are not shown. I tried playing around with the code itself as well, but everything I did made the app crash but I'm open to suggestions.

The problem (logged in as user 2) :

[image]

The database with two users and the two notes:

[image]

I've tried solutions from other similar posts like this:

```
    "rules": {
        "tasks": {
            "$userId": {
                ".read": "auth.uid == $userId",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $userId",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But none worked properly so far.

#### User creation:

```
fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    fUserDatabase.child(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("basic").child("name")
                            .setValue(name).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(mainIntent);
                                finish();
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                            } else {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            }
                        }
                    }); 

                } else {

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
            }
        });
```

#### Note Creation:

(Not on the same page)

```
editText = findViewById(R.id.etx);
        etd = findViewById(R.id.etdx);
        button = findViewById(R.id.btnx);


            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts").push();
                    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("id", databaseReference.getKey());
                    map.put("title", editText.getText().toString());
                    map.put("desc", etd.getText().toString());


                    databaseReference.setValue(map);
                    Intent back = new Intent(NewNoteActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(back);

                }
            });
```

I would like to make it so that every user can only see, edit and delete notes that they made themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that might be useful to anyone else who's having troubles with this kind of thing. 
I changed the path in the note creation to this:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("posts").push();
```

Then changed the part of the code that shows the notes accordingly. 
This is how it was:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("posts");
```

This is how it is now:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("posts");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot keep data as relational database. because firebase database is flat heierarchy. when you design the database use always

```
/users/user-id/posts 
                + item1
                + item2
```

this is the way you must implement. thanks.